# Is "gone" in the title of a youtube video "AUDITIONS GONE WRONG Angry Contestants" correct?

Tags: past-participles, headlinese

Below is a title of [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDm9hwchyUI).

> AUDITIONS **GONE** WRONG Angry Contestants & More | Idols Global

The word I am suspicious about in the title is **GONE**.

I know there are many expressions like "*something has gone wrong*", which is correct.
But this is not in a passive form.
"GONE" in the title of the video seems to have a passive quality, so I wonder whether the title is correct. I think it should be modified into as below.

> AUDITIONS **HAVING GONE** WRONG Angry Contestants & More | Idols Global

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could think of the headline as using a kind of *whiz-deletion*: Auditions *which have* gone wrong.  "Auditions having gone wrong" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

"Auditions gone wrong" is a perfectly acceptable shortening of "Auditions that have gone wrong," which is the meaning used here. News headlines and video titles often use shorter versions like this to make things brief and memorable.

"Auditions having gone wrong" is awkward and not really how a native speaker would construct this title even if they didn't want to shorten it. A native English speaker would instead prefer to use a relative clause like "that have gone wrong" in a context like this. "Having gone wrong" would be more appropriate in a context like "Having gone wrong, the auditions were cancelled early," though it's still a bit less than ideal even there.

Comment: Actually they are more likely to say `Auditions that went badly` than `Auditions that have gone wrong`.

Comment: @T54 I don't really agree there (I'd be more likely to say the latter or `Auditions that went wrong` myself), but regardless, it's the same *grammatical* construction - my point is more that they're more likely to use a relative clause in this context than a participle phrase.

Comment: Yeah your right it doesn't really matter. TBH I was really just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. The phrase

> AUDITIONS GONE WRONG

is perfectly acceptable (correct) within the English language, in the context of a [click bait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait) video.

Furthermore the title does not need to be modified but should the content creator which to change the title to

> AUDITIONS HAVING GONE WRONG Angry Contestants & More | Idols Global

It would still be correct as it is a matter of personal opinion.